# How to build dynamic css main/sub menu's (or do I need jquery)?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have the following css layout (see pic below) and would like to know if css supports dynamic sub menus (or do I need jquery for this)?  That is, when the mouse hovers over a main menu item, Home/Menu 1/Menu 2, I would like to dynamically update the sub menus below custom according to each main menu item.  Of course when the main menu item is selected the sub menu items stick accordingly.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What browser compatibility constraints are you under (e.g. do you need to support IE6)?

Comment: I... think you can? with something like `ul.mymenu:hover li.submenu{display:block}`. It's not cross-browser though... using javascript/jquery would be best I think.

Comment: Allowed browsers are all current revs of FF, Chrome & IE9/10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/Uk22m/).

### HTML

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href=#>Test1</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href=#>Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Test3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href=#>Test2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href=#>Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Test3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href=#>Test3</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href=#>Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Test3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul.mainmenu {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.mainmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.mainmenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #ff005a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.25em;
}

ul.mainmenu li a:hover {
    background: #ff00ff;
}

ul.mainmenu li ul.submenu {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}

ul.mainmenu li:hover > ul.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the space between each of the menu elements. You cannot access the submenu before it disappears.